# Отдать страницу в ".html" Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

Возможно ли как нибудь отдать такой адрес пользователю с содержимым ?

> localhost/post/namePost.html

Comment: не понимаю вопроса, что значит отдать

Comment: У меня есть на сайте товары.
Я хочу чтобы пользователь видел каталог товаров. Но при переходе на них открывался адрес согласно описанию этой темы

Comment: но эта ссылка будет работать только локально, только на вашем компьютере, конечно если не прописать на компьютере клиента локальный адрес

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это издевательство, но будет работать :)

```
Route::get('/{slug}{ext}',function($slug,$ext){
    return [$slug,$ext];
})->where(['slug'=>'[-_A-Za-z0-9]+','ext'=>'\..+']);
```